# block a command in ubuntu(in shell)

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line, makefile, alias

I am working on ubuntu server with 10 users at any point of time. We usually keep our code there and use the server to make builds. The build usually takes 30 to 50 minutes based on concurrency defined. The build command is `make -jX` where X can be anything from 1 to 24.

My problem starts when many users start giving make command with higher X value. Is there any way to block these commands or to put any limit.

For example, if someone gives `make -jX` (X>4), I should be able to override the command as `make -j4`.

I know one way is to use **alias** but I have no idea how to interpret the argument value through alias (like `alias ll='ls -la'` in .**bashrc** file is ok but how to interpret `ll -lha` through bashrc).

Also is there any way to make the alias work for all the users without editing the bashrc files of all the users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to block make command for perticular user?

Comment: no i want to make it generic, so that if anyone gives make with higher j value it should automatically fallback to default value

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command) at end they have given how to add options to aliases using shell script functions.may be this ll help you

Comment: this assumes your users won't figure out to avoid an alias/function that limits their access. Better to tell management that they need to buy a more servers ;-> . Good luck.

Comment: through alias how to neglect the arguments like alias make='make -j4' what if the user give the command as make -j8

Comment: @Shellter unfortunately we can't afford a new server at this moment of time :-) also since i have the root access so can i make this rule applicable to all the users?

Answer (score 1):

Although limiting the parameters to a particular command (in this case `make`) in a way that cannot be circumvented is generally hard, you can configure system-level process limits on each user using `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

If you open this file on your system, you will see in the comments that you can limits various user resources such as `nproc` and memory. If you play with these limits, you may be able to get something reasonable to get fair resource sharing among your developers.